# Run set of commands and return error code if any failed

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, automation, continuous-integration

In a nodejs project I have a shortcut `yarn lint` that runs couple of linters in such way:

```
lint_1 && lint_2 && lint_3
```

If any of these find an error it return an error code, as a result `yarn lint` itself returns error code, as a result - build fails.

It works somewhat fine, catches all the errors though there is a small issue: If a linter fails with error code - rest of the linters wont be executed.

What I would like - execute all of them (so they all print all errors) and only then fail.

I know that I can create a bash script (that I will run in `yarn lint`), run each of the linters one by one collecting return codes and then check if any of codes is non-zero - `exit 1` and it will fail the `yarn lint`. But I am wondering is there more elegant way to do it?

Comment: `&` runs in parallel. Do you mean `&&` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk, Oh right! Thank you for correction. Yes, I do `&&`, updated the question.

Comment: @SmxCde: What is wrong with the shell script? What other way are you looking to do this?

Comment: I guess a) I do not like the code I imagine, line for each call, line for each exit cod variable and naming each variable... and then `if` checkgin all variables in the end...

Comment: b) I am not too good at bash so I am afraid I am missing some trivial operator that could do it  easily

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could trap on ERR and set a flag. This would run each of the linters and exit with failure if any one of them fails:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=0
trap 'result=1' ERR
lint_1
lint_2
lint_3
exit "$result"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you please clarify for me, will it work if the error code for some reason is greater than 1? Does `trap 'result=1' ERR` mean "catch only code `1`"?

Comment: `trap ... ERR` here means "run any time a command exits with non-zero status (with all the caveats of `set -e`)". `result=1` is a regular variable assignment to be executed on this event

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Thank you very much, this is perfect.

Comment: This is a bash answer to a bash question. Fish is a different language.

Answer (score 3):

> What I would like - execute all of them (so they all print all errors) and only then fail

Basically we have a list of exit codes to catch. If any of them is nonzero, we need to set a variable to have nonzero value. Expanding that to a list, would look like this:

```
result=0
if ! lint_1; then result=1; fi
if ! lint_2; then result=1; fi
if ! lint_3; then result=1; fi
exit "$result"
```

As a programmer, I see that we have a pattern here. So we can go with an array, but bash does not have 2d arrays. It would be a workaround with `eval` to get around quoted parameters. It is doable. You have to use `eval`, to double evaulate the array "pointer"/name, but works. Note that `eval` is `evil`.

```
cmds_1=(lint_1 "arg with spaces you pass to lint_1")
cmds_2=(lint_2)
cmds_3=(lint_3)

result=0
# compgen results list of variables starting with `cmds_`
# so naming is important
for i in $(compgen -v cmds_); do
    # at first, `$i` is only expanded
    # then the array is expanded `"${cmds_?[@]}"`
    if ! eval "\"\${$i[@]}\""; then
        result=1
    fi
done
exit "$result"
```

We can also go with [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html). From manual `EXIT STATUS` is `123 if __any__ invocation of the command exited with status 1-125`. If you know that your programs will exit between 1-125 exit status you can (usually xargs handles different exit statuses correctly anyway (returns 123), but let's stay conforming):

```
xargs -l1 -- bash -c '"$@"' -- <<EOF
lint_1 "arg with spaces you pass to lint_1"
lint_2
lint_3
EOF
result=$?          # or just exit "$?"
exit "$result"
```

which looks strangely clean. On a side note, by passing just `-P <number of jobs>` to `xargs` you can execute all the command in parallel. You can accommodate for the 1-125 error range, by handling the error inside the bash script, ie.

```
xargs -l1 -- bash -c '"$@" || exit 1' -- <<EOF
lint_1 "arg with spaces you pass to lint_1"
lint_2
lint_3
EOF
result=$?
exit "$result"
```

And I have another idea. After each command we can output the return status on a dedicated file descriptor. Then from all return statuses filter zeros and check if there are any other statuses on the stream. If they are, we should exit with nonzero status. This feels like a work-done-around and is basically the same as the first code snipped, but the `if ! ....; then result=1; fi` is simplified to `; echo $? >&10`.

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
(
    lint_1 "arg with spaces you pass to lint_1"; echo $? >&10
    lint_2; echo $? >&10
    lint_3; echo $? >&10
) 10> >(
    [ -z "$(grep -v 0)" ]
    echo $? > "$tmp"
)
result="$(cat "$tmp"; rm "$tmp")"
exit "$result"
```

From the options presented, I would go with the other answer ;) or with the xargs second snipped.

Comment: Thanks for such extended answer, I am still looking at the options :)

Comment: Can I ask, why result is in quotes `exit "$result"` and would `exit ${result}` work instead?

Comment: Because I always quote variables. Unless don't. But usually always quote. See https://www.shellcheck.net/ and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I had to go with That Other Guy's answer, it works beter for my case, but your suggestions are also great for many other cases, so I voted for it too.

Comment: @KamilCuk "usually always quote". Got it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this clean, clear, and succinct:

```bash
declare -i result=0  # declare $result is an integer

lint_1; result+=$?
lint_2; result+=$?

exit "$result"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to to update accepted answer like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=0
trap '((result+=e))' ERR
e=1; lint_1
e=2; lint_2
e=4; lint_3
exit "$result"
```

This will allow to easily understand which one(or many) failed.